# How do I set my ion-datetime to today's date automatically without needing to click the picker beforehand?

Tags: html, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want my date and time to automatically display the current date and time without needing to click the picker first.

**The output I want is as below:**

[image]

**As above, I want my app to directly take the current date and time without the need of user to click the picker first.**

All this while my current app uses the default code from ionic documentation where the user need to click the picker to see and choose current date or time like below:

[image]

[image]

My current html code is as follows:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-list-header>
    <ion-label>
      Tarikh & Masa Kesalahan:
    </ion-label>
  </ion-list-header>   
    
      <ion-card>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-datetime dateFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="form.tarikh_pemeriksaan"></ion-datetime>
          <ion-icon name="calendar" slot="end"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-card>

  <ion-card>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-datetime display-format="h:mm A" picker-format="h:mm A" value="1990-02-19T07:43Z" placeholder="--:-- --" [(ngModel)]="form.masa"></ion-datetime>
      <ion-icon name="time" slot="end"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

My typescript code is as below:

```
export class FcPage implements OnInit {

  form: any = {}
  premis: any = {};
  negeri: any;
  negeripenerima:any;
  daerah: any;
  daerahpenerima: any;
  daerahpenggerak: any;
  daerahindividu: any;
  loading: boolean;
  service: any;
  userdetail: any = {}
  perundangan: any = {};
  kesalahan: any = {};
  senarai_kesalahan: any = {};
  peraturan: any = {}
  projek: any = {};
  jpunca: any = {};
  checked : boolean = false;

  constructor(
    public api: ApiService,
    public modalController: ModalController,
    public router: Router,
    private userData: UserData,
  ) { 
    this.form = {}
    this.form.showCetak = false;
    this.senarai_kesalahan = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jas_item_kesalahan'));
    //this.form.tarikh_pemeriksaan = new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0];
    this.form.tarikh_pemeriksaan = this.form.masa = new Date().toISOString();
  } 

    ngOnInit() {
      this.getNegeri();
      this.getNegeriPenerima();
      this.getDaerah();
      this.getDaerahPenerima();
      this.getDaerahIndividu();
      this.getDaerahAll();
      this.getJenisPunca();
      this.getUserDetail();
      this.getUsermisc();
      this.senarai_kesalahan = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jas_item_kesalahan'));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the initial value of form.tarikh_pemeriksaan and form.masa to current date

```
form.tarikh_pemeriksaan = form.masa = new Date().toISOString();
```

Comment: I've put this in my constructor in typescript but still it makes me click the picker first to get the current date and time. I want the output which does not need to click the picker first instead it shows current date and time initially and the user can click the picker to change.

Comment: Yeah there is a minor change. I have updated the code above. You have to convert the date to string using .toISOString()

Comment: Thank you @Vijay However the field still remains empty when I enter the page. I still need to click on the field to get current date / time.

Comment: You must have updated the 'form' somewhere after assigning the date into it in constructor. It should work without an issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Before your contructor** in your TypeScript file you can do this:
`export class TestPage {`
`this.form.tarikh_pemeriksaan = new Date();`
`this.form.masa = new Date();`
`constructor(){}`
`}`

Then in your HTML file you call your variable in **NgModel** like you done before. I Think that will resolve your problem.

Comment: I've put my typescript code in the question. Please check how should I amend your codes in my .ts file as above. When I put in your codes as you requested, I gain error saying object is undefined

Comment: Please I forgot to remove **this** on variables before constructor. You have to declare variables and initiate with **new Date()**. I'm very sorry. Don't write **this.form.tarikh_permeriksaan** , but create an object like this: `form = {tarikh_pemeriksaan : new Date(),  masa: new Date()};` . I hope That, it will be helpful and will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor in TypeScript you can do this to have actual date and time.

```
this.form.tarikh_pemeriksaan = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
this.form.masa = moment(new Date()).format("HH:mm");
```

Comment: Thank you @IreneC but actually I've gotten the actual date and time already using default ion-datetime. I have no problem in achieving the current date/time instead I have problem in showing the current date/time before user click the picker.

Comment: Hi Miro. I don't understand well your problem. With the lines I put you, when you enter on the page you must have actual date and time on the fields

Comment: I've tried to put in your code but I cant use the 'moment' function. It gives me error

Comment: Sorry. It's my fault. You must install momentJS and import it.